# Event “editable-save.bs.table” how to get entire data sent to server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm using the `bootstrapTable` with the `editable` extension, init it with:

```
$table.bootstrapTable({
  data: [JSON data from server]
});
```

I click the column, edit the value, and after it's done - the event `editable-save.bs.table` is being called with the following information:

```
$table.on('editable-save.bs.table', function(editable, field, row, oldValue, $el) {
            console.log("editable:", editable);
            console.log("field:", field);
            console.log("row", row);
            console.log("oldValue", oldValue);
            console.log("el", $el);
        });
```

But in order to save the current state of the table - I want to get the **entire** data of the table, lets say - I want to receive
`$table.data` above ...

You can see http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/12585/ ( with the console opened ) just to get a sense of what you receive after editing the row ( the blue links are clickable )
How can I extract this information ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, apperantly I need to call again the `bootstrapTable` on the table ...

```
$table.bootstrapTable('getData')
```